Is this reduction from Exact 1-in-3-SAT to Subset Sum using Horowitz and Sahni's algorithm known?
I'm exploring a reduction from Exact 1-in-3-SAT (x3SAT) to the Subset Sum problem that allows the use of the Horowitz and Sahni algorithm, achieving a time complexity of
$\mathcal{O^*}(2^{/2})$ for x3SAT.
The reduction works as follows:

Variables and Initialization:

For each variable $u_i$ in the x3SAT instance, create a corresponding variable $x_i$ in the Subset Sum instance with an initial coefficient $c_i=0$.
Initialize the target sum $S=0$


Processing Each Clause:

For each clause with index  $k$ in the x3SAT instance:

Let $=8^k$ (or another sufficiently large constant to ensure uniqueness among clauses)
Update the target sum and coefficients:

$S \mathrel{+}= z$
For each literal $l$ in the clause:

If $l$ is a positive literal $u_i$:

$c_i \mathrel{+}= z$


If $l$ is a negative literal $¬u_i$:

$c_i \mathrel{-}= z$
$ \mathrel{-}= z$











Rationale:
This construction ensures that the Subset Sum instance corresponds to the x3SAT instance in such a way that a solution to the Subset Sum problem corresponds to a satisfying assignment of the x3SAT instance where exactly one literal in each clause is true.
The number of variables in the Subset Sum instance equals the number of variables in the x3SAT instance, allowing the application of the Horowitz and Sahni algorithm with a time complexity of $\mathcal{O^*}(2^{n/2})$.
My Question:

Is this reduction already known in the literature?
If so, could you provide references or point me to related work?

Note: Above, parts of this question were rephrased using gpt. These parts were manually curated afterwards.
Proof of correctness (added 20 Nov 2024, without the help of GPT):
A. It should be clear that any solution to the x3SAT instance is also a solution to the subset sum instance:

a clause with 3 positive literals contributes an amount of $z$ to $S$. Since a solution should have exactly 1 of these variables set to True, the clause will also contribute $z$ to the sum. (We use "sum" as the result of the additions, and "$S$" as the target)
a clause with 3 negative literals contributes an amount of $-2z$ to $S$. Any solution should have exactly 2 of these variables set to True, contributing $-2z$ to the sum, as each variable that's set to True in a negative literal, contributes $-z$ to the sum.
In the other two cases it can be checked likewise that when exactly one literal becomes true, the contribution of the variables of the clause to the sum is the same as the contribution of that clause to $S$.

B. The opposite case is less obvious, but still True: Every solution to the subset sum instance is also a solution to the x3SAT instance.
B1. Within a clause the cases can be checked just like under (A):

If there are 3 positive literals, then any solution to the subset sum instance will have exactly 1 variable in its selection if we consider only this clause, because otherwise the sum will be different than this clause's contribution.
The other cases within a clause can be checked similarly.

B2. The challenge remains to prove that any solution to the subset-sum instance leads to a selection of exactly 1 literal in each clause.
Consider the vector $v$ that lists the factors of the contributions of each clause to $S$, with items $v_k$. We have $v_k \in \{-2, -1, 0, 1\}$ ($v_k$ is simply defined as 1 minus the number of negative literals in clause $k$). Clause $k$ contributes $8^kv_k$ to $S$, and $S=\Sigma_k8^kv_k$
We need to prove that there can be no other vector $v'\neq v$ such that $S=\Sigma_k8^kv'_k$. In other words, we need to prove that if we have a solution to the subset-sum instance that contributes $8^kv'_k$ to the target sum for clause $k$ with $v'_k \in \{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3\}$, then  $\forall k: v'_k=v_k$.
We start with $v$ and $v'$ and we need to prove that they are equal. Create vectors $v^+$ and $v'^+$ as follows:
From $v$ and $v'$, move all negative values to the other vector so that they become positive:

$v_k^+ = \max(v_k, 0) + |\min(v_k', 0)|$
$v_k'^+ = \max(v_k', 0) + |\min(v_k, 0)|$

This doesn't affect the same-ness of the vectors, nor does it affect the same-ness of their sums (saying, $v = v' \Longleftrightarrow v^+ = v'^+$, and $\Sigma_k8^{k}v_{k} = \Sigma_{k}8^{k}v_{k}' \Longleftrightarrow \Sigma_k8^{k}v^{+}_{k} = \Sigma_{k}8^{k}v_{k}'^+$). We have $v_k^+,v_k'^+ \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. It now remains to prove that $\Sigma_k8^{k}v^{+}_{k} = \Sigma_{k}8^{k}v_{k}'^+ \Rightarrow v^{+}=v'^{+}$. In the context of these sums the items of $v^+$ and $v'^+$ are treated as the digits of octal numbers (because they are multiplied by $8^k$ and they're between 0 and 8). Since each octal string represents a unique number, it follows that $v^+ = v'^+$ (QED).

Are you sure you want to subtract $z$ from $S$? Then, if a clause contains one negative literal, the clause does not contribute to $S$.

Yes I'm sure about the subtraction: In your case where a clause doesn't contribute to S (2 pos and 1 neg), any assignments also need to make sure that their net contribution is zero for that clause. About gpt, I let it help me rephrase and summarize the list after submitting my full paper to it. The idea and construction are fully mine and I fully handcrafted the list to use latex.

I'm not familiar with the reduction, but it's not clear to me why it should be correct, so you would first need to prove that.

@JohnKemeny, I added the proof. Please let me know if clarification is needed. I appreciate your patience.
